# SFML Visual Studio 2013 - project wont compile

Tags: c++, sfml

I have problems with compiling project with SFML libs. Before I even tryed to compile source of libs myself with Cmake but got other issues and all libs wasn't compiling. In cause of that I downloaded already compiled libs SFML2.1 for vc11, x64 and added them to project properties but I recieve strange errors like:

```
 Error  5   error LNK1120: 4 unresolved externals   C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio                  2013\Projects\Komparator cen ASG\Debug\Komparator cen ASG.exe  Komparator cen ASG
 Error  4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Http::~Http(void)" (__imp_??1Http@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Komparator cen ASG\Komparator cen ASG\Main.obj    Komparator cen ASG
 Error  3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Http::Http(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,unsigned short)" (__imp_??0Http@sf@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@G@Z) referenced in function _main    C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Komparator cen ASG\Komparator cen ASG\Main.obj    Komparator cen ASG
 Error  2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Http::Request::~Request(void)" (__imp_??1Request@Http@sf@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _main  C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Komparator cen ASG\Komparator cen ASG\Main.obj    Komparator cen ASG
 Error  1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall sf::Http::Request::Request(class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &,enum sf::Http::Request::Method,class std::basic_string<char,struct std::char_traits<char>,class std::allocator<char> > const &)" (__imp_??0Request@Http@sf@@QAE@ABV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@W4Method@012@0@Z) referenced in function _main   C:\Users\Konrad\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\Komparator cen ASG\Komparator cen ASG\Main.obj    Komparator cen ASG
```

Code I tryed to compile:

```
  #include <SFML/Network/Http.hpp>
  #include <string.h>

 using namespace std;

 int main()
 {
     string www = "http://www.gunfire.pl/";
     sf::Http site("http://www.gunfire.pl/");

     sf::Http::Request request(www);
     //request.setUri(www);
     request.Get;

     return 0;
 }
```

I know it may sound weird but I tryed to run SFML libs on VS13 plenty of times and already wasted a lot of time.

Comment: That's a linkage error, not a compilation error. Are you sure this one doesn't help you? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9788619/working-with-sfml-getting-unresolved-external-symbol-output?rq=1

Comment: Did you add the SFML library files to the linker input files for your project? It sounds like the linker doesn't know you're trying to use SFML...

Comment: Also, it's dangerous to use the vc11 libraries with vc12 (VS2013) -- if the ABI changed between versions, there could be subtle (or not so subtle) bugs caused by the mismatch between the code compiled in your project and the code already compiled into the library.

Comment: I personally prefer to build SFML from sources alongside my own code; much less hassle.

Comment: Finally got it to work, thanks. Already compiled libs haven't worked for me  so I compiled dynamic libs myself. Do I have to copy .dll files to folder with .exe file? Anyway I have other problem compiling SFML: During compilation it says: Unable to start program '\...\Cmake-build\lib\Release\sfml-audio-2.dll Does anyone know how to solve it?

Comment: @kondzio14 You probably have the 'sfml-audio' project set as your startup project, so either ignore the message, or set it to one of the other SFML projects.  As for your other question, yes you can copy the .dlls to the folder with the .exe in it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can compile a project in VS2013 with libs compiled for VS2012(VC11).
BUT
When you get to the point of Graphics.draw() you will head right into problems, because the  SFML version is not built for 2013.

The "unresolved external symbol" is one of the symptoms I faced, too.

Unfortunatley it is simple as that. If you want to use it for VS2013 you have to compile it your own, as you stated.

Againg, unfortunately, There are some bugs in 2013 that prevent you from building the static libraries.

As far as I know, there is no solution yet for building SFML 2.1 for VS2013. If there is, I would be very interested.

Comment: You can find here, http://sfml.my-gate.net/nightly/, unofficial nightly builds by exploiter(SFML team member). For me it worked.